# You have error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds your SQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Hi im new to visual studio i always get this error "You have error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds your SQL"

Here is my code and please help me thank you

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim MysqlConn As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection

    Dim UsersCommand As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand

    Dim UsersAdapter As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter

    Dim UsersData As New DataTable

    Dim SQL As String
    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        MysqlConn = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection()
        ' Define the SQL to prob data from table.
        SQL = "Select  FROM wala"
        'Connection String
        MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;" & "user id=Taena;" & "password=Taena;" & "database=wala"
        Try
            MysqlConn.Open()
            UsersCommand.Connection = MysqlConn
            UsersCommand.CommandText = SQL
            UsersAdapter.SelectCommand = UsersCommand
            UsersAdapter.Fill(UsersData)
            DataGridView1.DataSource = UsersData

        Catch myerror As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to database1" & myerror.Message)
        Finally
            MysqlConn.Close()
            MysqlConn.Dispose()

        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 2):

You missed which columns you want to select from your `wala` tzable. `*` is all columns. Try

```
Select * FROM wala
```

or even better specify the columns you need like this

```
select id, other_column from wala
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Select  FROM wala
```

You aren't telling it what to select - try

```
Select * FROM wala
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify either column names or * in the place of select query. That's all Simple.